# How do I write CSV data to a variable?

Tags: php, csv, export-to-csv

I am reading some data from my database, and I want to convert it into a csv to be displayed. But, I DON'T want to write to a file - is there any way to convert array data into a csv string without using a temporary file?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is. It is possible to use `php://memory` as if it was a file output stream, although it actually only writes to memory, not to a file.

For example, to convert the array `$data` into csv format `$rows`:

```
$rows = array();
$fd = fopen('php://memory','rw');
foreach($data as $datum) {
    fputcsv($fd, $datum);
    rewind($fd);
    $rows[] = trim(fgets($fd));
    rewind($fd);
}
fclose($fd);
```

Here you can see I open the memory for reading/writing, then for each data set, I write the data as csv - then rewind to the start of the memory - then read the contents of the memory. Note that fputcsv always terminates the line with a newline, which is why I can use fgets to read the line without having to worry about overflow. You may need to change it a bit if you are storing data containing newlines, as fgets won't work then and you'll need to do some more elaborate checking/validation, and the maximum size of `php:://memory` is defined in php.ini.

Comment: This was helpful, though I'm not sure why you went to all the trouble with the array? `$fd = fopen('php://memory', 'rw'); array_map(fn($row, $i) => fputcsv($fd, $row), $data); $csv = stream_get_contents($fd, offset: 0); fclose($fd);`